# Setting rcParameters after importing pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

According to http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.use one hast to set the matplotlib backend with matplotlib.use before importing pyplot. Is this also true for other rcParameters? Which rcParameteres can safely be set after importing pyplot?

Answer (score 0):

No, other `rcParams` can be set dynamically after import. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) for more information.

> You can also dynamically change the default rc settings in a python
>   script or interactively from the python shell. All of the `rc` settings
>   are stored in a dictionary-like variable called `matplotlib.rcParams`,
>   which is global to the `matplotlib` package. `rcParams` can be modified
>   directly, for example:
>
> ```
> import matplotlib as mpl 
> mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
> mpl.rcParams['lines.color'] = 'r'
> ```
>
> Matplotlib also provides a couple of
>   convenience functions for modifying `rc` settings. The `matplotlib.rc()`
>   command can be used to modify multiple settings in a single group at
>   once, using keyword arguments:
>
> ```
> import matplotlib as mpl mpl.rc('lines', linewidth=2, color='r')
> ```